# Looping through asset types from Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code that needs to branch depending on if a value from a database is absent. Essentially our database contains some key value pairs from a dictionary. If the key is absent from a set, we should append zero as the value for that key. Otherwise, we should append the value from the database.

```py
values = []
known_asset_types = {'A', 'B', 'C'}
total_external_assets = assets_service.get_total_external_assets().items()
visible_asset_types = set()
# total_external_assets is a dictionary
for db_asset_type, asset_count in total_external_assets:
            if db_asset_type in known_asset_types:
                visible_asset_types.add(asset_type)
                values.append({"name": db_asset_type, "value": asset_count})
      
for asset in known_asset_types.difference(visible_asset_types):
      values.append({"name": asset, "value": 0})
```

Is there a simpler or more pythonic way to accomplish what I'm doing? I got a comment saying I can loop through the `known_asset_types` and check if the key is in `total_external_assets` and if `True` use that value else `zero`, but having a nested loop feels...worse to me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with nested loops. It's the body of the loop that matters. More or less every nontrivial program is bunch of "nested" loops. Except that more often then not they're not really nested, but rather hidden in function calls that themselves hide another loop(s). In your case going from known_asset_types will require total_external_assets to be a map rather than a list, otherwise that would be ineffective.

Comment: In fact your current implementation would also benefit if known_asset_types was a set because of the `if-in` check which is linear in time for list and it's constant in time on sets.

Comment: Btw in two instances you refer to variable db_asset_type as just asset_type. Please fix it so that your question is not closed as not working correctly.

Comment: @BCdotWEB perhaps you already saw but in case not: the OP [updated the title in revision 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/281580/2).

Comment: Since the question is closed you can edit it to add details and make it work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code doesn't work. When you loop over `total_external_assets` you don't get a key-value pair tuple but instead just the keys. You need to access `.items()` to get both.

I also don't follow what you mean by a nested loop. The suggestion you got from a colleague was to loop over `known_asset_types` *instead of* looping over `total_external_assets`. This seems reasonable if you only care about the `known_asset_types`, which it appears that you do; you'll have to process way fewer items, and to then get the value of a key in `known_asset_types` from `total_external_assets` is then only a hashmap/dictionary lookup, which is O(1) - i.e. very fast.

This

```
if db_asset_type in known_asset_types:
    visible_asset_types.add(asset_type)
    values.append({"name": db_asset_type, "value": asset_count})
```

is also a bit unnecessary; you're first looking for the item, and if it exists you retrieve it. That's two lookups when you only needed a single one. You can do

```
try:
    asset = known_asset_types[db_asset_type]
except KeyError:  # doesn't exist
    pass
else:  # does exist
    visible_asset_types.add(db_asset_type)
    values.append({"name": db_asset_type, "value": asset})
```

Finally, you should know that you can replace

```
try:
    value = dict[key]
except KeyError:
    value = default
```

with

```
value = dict.get(key, default)
```

Comment: sorry I made an error when copy pasting my code. `total_external_assets` is indeed a dictionary's `.items()` method.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to generate a dictionary of the following form:

- The keys should be the ones enumerated in `known_asset_types`
- The values should be either the value from `total_external_assets` if the key is present in that dictionary, otherwise 0.

In that case, your best bet is to use python's dictionary `.get()` method.

This allows you to handle a missing key and return a default value.

For example

```
{'A':1}.get('A', '?') # returns 1
{'A':1}.get('B', '?') # returns '?'
```

Using this you can create the dictionary as follows using a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: total_external_assets.get(k,0) for k in known_asset_types}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! In my code I've commented that `total_external_assets` is already a dictionary.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I can't append `asset_type` as the "name" value when the `asset_type` is not found as a key in `total_external_assets`

Comment: What would you set as the name if the key is not in `total_external_assets`?

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. While this might be a good answer on stackoverflow, it is not a good answer on Code Review. A good answer on Code Review contains at least one insightful observation about the code. Alternate code only solutions are considered poor answers and may be down voted or deleted by the community. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But also, all the solutions begin with a loop over `total_external_assets`, so they keys in the output will be a subset of the keys in `total_external_assets`

Comment: Thank you @pacmaninbw - I'll adapt in the future.

Comment: so if `known_asset_types` include `A, B, C` but only `B` and `C` are found in `total_external_assets`, I want the output to include `{A: 0}`

Comment: try this:
`{k: total_external_assets.get(k,0) for k in known_asset_types}`
That gives you that output.

Comment: Hi MYK, please can you [edit] your answer to be inline with the rules pacmaninbw indicated before. Doing so originally would likely avoid the rather long comment exchange you've gotten. As you'd have thought out and clear improvements, reducing the likely hood of you posting code which performs a different algorithm. Additionally if the code does perform the same, then the OP would likely be able to understand without commenting. Failure to bring your answer inline with the site's rules will result in actions being taken against your answer.

Comment: See new version